# How to set up Magit to access a GitHub repository?

Tags: magit, github

How can I set up Magit to access a GitHub repository?

Comment: What aspect of "accessing a Github repository" didn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: @tarsius: I have not tried anything yet except for reading the Introduction, Installation, Post Installation, and Getting Started sections of the Magit manual. I couldn't find any explanation on how to access a GitHub repository. I don't want to install this package before I know whether it's possible to access a GitHub repository. By "accessing a GitHub repository" I mean creating a branch, downloading the latest version of a file, committing a file, reviewing diffs, merging, etc.

Comment: magit can do anything command line git can.

Comment: First, learn how magit basics to clone and "access" the github repository. Then, you'll find [more github tools](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Github) here, including magithub that extends magit to fetch issues, pull requests, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't configure Magit to access a remote Git repository. Instead you configure `git` and because Magit uses `git`, Magit is then also able to do so.

Some issues can arise due to misconfiguration and/or Windows not having a concept of a pty. But even then, the solution is to properly configure Git and/or Emacs. No additional Magit configuration is required. (Except if you use some two-factor authentication, then you might have to adjust `magit-process-password-prompt-regexps`).

Some of the difficulties that might arise, are covered in [this wiki page](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows).

Comment: Thanks. But my question remains, if in a slightly different formulation: What steps do I need to take, after installing Magit, in order that Magit will work vis-a-vis a given GitHub repository?

Comment: Assuming that you are already able to "access Github" when using git on the command line, there is a 99% chance that the answer is "none". If you are using Windows, then the probability only is 95%. The 4% difference is due to you possibly having to do "setx HOME C:/path/to/home". I cannot help you any further until you have actually tried. Once you have tried and have run into a problem, I or someone else will help you though.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `magit-clone` to clone a GitHub (or any Git) repo

   - You can also clone via command line, of course, which I prefer
2. Open a file in the repo and call `magit-status`

   - It is convenient to bind this to a key, e.g. `C-c m`

Congratulations, you're using Magit.

Howard Abrams' excellent [introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQO7F2Q9DwA) can get you started with staging, committing, pushing, etc. A comprehensive [user manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html) is also available.

> I don't want to install this package before I know whether it's possible to access a GitHub repository.

Uhh...where's the spirit of experimentation?